# TypeError: Error #1006: myInitializer is not a function. - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, typeerror

I'm having a difficult time working on my flash application. Everytime I run my code, this error bumps at me.

> TypeError: Error #1006: myInitializer is not a function.

I am quite sure that my myInitializer() function is indeed a function:

```
public class newClass extends MovieClip {
    public function newClass() {
    this.width = this.width;
    this.height = this.height;
    }

    public function myInitializer(initX:Number, initY:Number):void {
        this.y = initY;
        this.x = initX;
    }
}
```

and this is how I call it from another as file:

```
myClass = new newClass();
myClass.myInitializer(161, 380);
```

any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0):

Is that a Typo ?

**myClasss**.myInitializer(161, 380);

Comment: yes, it is a typo. but it didn't fix the problem. well apparently, OOP's rules include the case sensitivity of filenames so i had to make sure that my filenames and class names are the same case-sensitivity wise. that solved the problem. thanks. :)